# Send method body runtime and then execute it?

Tags: c#

Code example:

```
byte[] DownloadMethodKill()
{
    return new WebClient().DownloadBytes("http://192.168.0.100/methodKill");
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Method method = DownloadMethodKill();
    method();
}
```

Assuming the downloaded method body of `Kill` prints in console `"hey i'm killed 2 3"`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, this sounds like a terrible idea and ripe for some kind of horrible exploit.

But: there's two ways to approach this; sending IL fragments *in isolation* isn't very useful, but *one option* is to send an *assembly*, but that then has complex demands on both ends having the exact same runtime etc - not very maintainable. The other approach is to send something that *represents* the operation, but in a parseable form - then *parse it* at the client. This could be some kind of simple expression - there are lots of expression parsers/compilers available - or you could run the whole thing through Roslyn and send it as C# (for example).

There's also `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody` and `MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody` - which work on a `byte[]` of raw IL, but those are *very advanced topics*, and again: frankly I think it would be the wrong way to do this. They also have the same problems again re runtimes.